# laravel 10 livewire 3 component button questions

Tags: laravel, alpine.js, livewire-3

I am brand new in Laravel, Livewire, & Alpine. I am creating a CRUD page that displays data in a table, has a button to load an edit form, has a delete button, and will have a form to add a row. I am having trouble with several things.

1. When I load a data row to the edit form, why does the table become empty?
2. How do I pass the data from the edit form to the update function?
3. How do I confirm delete before calling the delete function.

The Bookings class successfully loads data to the table. The editBooking function successfully loads the selected row of data to the edit form. However, the save button does not succeed in calling the updateBooking function. Even a `dd('alert');` in the update function does not display anything. Also, I would like to pass just the selected row of data to the function without needing to query the database again by the passed booking id.

I have tried several delete buttons. The Alpine-style one will call the Delete function and should work. However, in the alpine syntax, the `wire:confirm="confirm"` fails. The other buttons using wire:click and dispatch, appear to do nothing.

The code is just Bookings.php and bookings.blade.php (which uses a main.blade.php).

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Bookings;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Booking;
use App\Models\Participant;

// bookings livewire app/Livewire/Bookings/Bookings.php

class Bookings extends Component
{
    public $bookings, $id, $pptidtype, $pptid
            ,$bookId
            , $fhs_idtype_id
            ,$exam_type, $exam_type_desc, $exam_no, $exam_location, $exam_location_desc
            ,$reschedule, $exstat, $refuse_reason, $exam_date
            ,$content
            ;


    protected $listeners = ['deleteBooking'];

    public function render()
    {
        $fhs_idtype_id = request('fhs_idtype_id');
        $bookings = Booking::where('fhs_idtype_id', '=',  $fhs_idtype_id)->get();
        $this->bookings  = $bookings;
        $participants = Participant::where('fhs_idtype_id', $fhs_idtype_id )->get();
        // dump('Bookings LW render', $fhs_idtype_id, $bookings);

        return view('livewire.bookings.bookings')->with('bookings', $bookings )
        ->with('fhs_idtype_id', $fhs_idtype_id)
        ->with('participants', $participants )
        ;
    }

    public function editBooking($booking)
    {
        // dump('editBooking', $booking['id'] ); // $this->bookings  , $booking->exam_type_desc gettype($booking)
        $this->bookId =  $booking['id'];
        $this->exam_type = $booking['exam_type']; // $this->bookings->exam_type;
        // $this->exam_type_desc = 'editBooking desc';
        $this->exam_type_desc =  $booking['exam_type_desc'];
        
    }

    public function updateBooking()
    {
        dump('updateBooking' );
        $this->content = 'updateBook'; //attempt to update a textbox as an alert.
    }
    public function save()
    {
        dump('saveupdateBooking' );
        $this->content = 'saveupdateBook'; //attempt to update textbox for alert
    }

    #[On('deleteTriggered')]
    public function deleteBooking($id) // bookId , $booking->exam_type_desc
    {
        // dd('DEL Book',$id);

        try{
            $booking = Booking::find($id);
            // Booking::find($id)->delete();
            dd('DEL Book',$id, $booking->exam_type_desc);

        }catch(\Exception $e){
            session()->flash('error',"deleteBooking");
        }
    }

}
```

bookings.blade.php

```
<div>
    {{-- Livewire bookings blade --}}


@extends('main')

@section('page-title', 'Bookings')

@section('page-content')


    <h1 title='/var/www/pts2/resources/views/livewire/bookings/bookings.blade.php'>Booking LW</h1>

    @if ($fhs_idtype_id)

        <ul>
            <li><a href='/bookings/lw/{{ $fhs_idtype_id }}'>a link that would call this page, Bookings LW</a></li>
        </ul>


        <div class="w3-row-padding">
            @if ($bookings)
            <table class="w3-table-all">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>FHS ID</th><th>Exam Type</th><th>Exam No.</th>
                    <th>Exam Location</th><th>Reschedule</th>
                    <th>Exam Status</th><th>Refuse Reason</th>
                    <th>Exam Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>

                @foreach ($bookings as $booking)
                    <tr wire:key="bookings-{{ $booking->id }}"><td>
                        {{-- <td>{{ $booking->pptid}}</td> --}}
                        <td>bid:{{$booking->id}}. {{ $booking->fhs_idtype_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $booking->exam_type}} {{ $booking->exam_type_desc}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $booking->exam_no}}</td>
                        <td>
                            {{ $booking->exam_location}} {{ $booking->exam_location_desc}}
                            {{-- <livewire:counter :count="$booking->exam_location"/> --}}
                        </td>
                        
                        <td>{{ $booking->reschedule}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $booking->exstat}} {{ $booking->exstat_desc}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $booking->refuse_reason}}</td>
                        <td>{{ $booking->exam_date}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <span>id:{{$booking->id}}</span>
                            <button wire:click.prevent="editBooking({{$booking}})" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit{{$booking->id}} </button> {{-- loads the edit text boxes --}}

                            <button type="button" 
                                x-on:click="$wire.deleteBooking({{$booking->id}})"
                                title='Alpine calls delete'
                            >DELETE Alpine</button> {{-- succeeds in calling func --}}

                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                wire:confirm="Confirm Delete Booking:{{ $booking->id }}."
                                wire:click="$parent.deleteBooking({{ $booking->id }})"
                                title="only confirm works"
                            >
                                wire click only confirm works.
                            </button>
                              

                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                @click="$dispatch('deleteTriggered', { id: {{ $booking->id }} })"
                                {{-- wire:click="$dispatch('deleteTriggered', '{{ $booking->id }}')" --}}
                                {{-- wire:click=$dispatch('deleteTriggered', { id: {{ $booking->id }} }) --}}
                                title="does nothing"
                            >
                                at-click dispatch does nothing
                            </button>

                            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
                                wire:click=$dispatch('deleteTriggered', { id: {{ $booking->id }} })
                                title="does nothing"
                            >
                                at-click dispatch does nothing
                            </button>
                              
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        @else
            <p>booking not found</p>
        @endif

        </div>
        <div class="w3-row-padding-padding w3-border">
            <div>
                <h4>Add</h4> This is not yet implemented.
            </div>

            <div><h4>Edit</h4>
                {{-- <form wire:submit="save"> --}}
                <form >
                    <input type="number" wire:model="bookId">
                    <input type="number" wire:model="exam_type">
                 
                    <input type="text" wire:model="exam_type_desc">
                    <input type="text" wire:model="content">
                 <br>
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                    <button wire:click.prevent="updateBooking()" class="w3-btn w3-border w3-round">Update does nothing</button>
                    <span x-text="$wire.bookId.length"></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    @endif
 {{-- </div>div is out of place, but it breaks without --}}

@endsection
```